# Populating ListView with data from Parse.com failed

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, listview-adapter

I used AndroidBegin guide to populate my ListView with data from Parse.com table (http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/) and it shows an empty ListView.

```
// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuestionsList.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        if (AnswerActivity.friend.isEmpty()) {
            if (AnswerActivity.wantedTop == AnswerActivity.all) {
                // Locate the class table named "Info" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Info");

                // Locate the column named "Views" in Parse.com and order list by ascending
                query.orderByDescending("Views");
                try {
                    ob = query.find();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            } else {
                // Locate the class table named "Info" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Info");

                // Search for the wanted topic
                query.whereContains("User_Topic", AnswerActivity.wantedTop);

                // Locate the column named "Views" in Parse.com and order list by ascending
                query.orderByDescending("Views");
                try {
                    ob = query.find();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            if (AnswerActivity.wantedTop == AnswerActivity.all) {
                // Locate the class table named "Info" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Info");

                // Search for the wanted topic
                query.whereContains("User_Name", AnswerActivity.friend);

                // Locate the column named "Views" in Parse.com and order list by ascending
                query.orderByDescending("Views");
                try {
                    ob = query.find();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            } else {
                // Locate the class table named "Info" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Info");

                // Search for the wanted topic
                query.whereContains("User_Topic", AnswerActivity.wantedTop);
                query.whereContains("User_Name", AnswerActivity.friend);

                // Locate the column named "Views" in Parse.com and order list by ascending
                query.orderByDescending("Views");
                try {
                    ob = query.find();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
             }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(QuestionsList.this,
                R.layout.listview_item);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent i = new Intent(QuestionsList.this,
                        SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name")
                        .toString());
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Later, I used ParseQueryAdapter tutorial, but still, it doesn't work.

Someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Could you post the (relevant) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a parse query factory

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post> factory;
factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post>() {
                @Override
                public ParseQuery<Post> create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("YourParseObject");
                    return query;
                }
            };
```

make a parse query adapter

```
private ParseQueryAdapter<Post> adapter;
adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Post>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(final Post object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.post_item, null);
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
    adapter.setPaginationEnabled(true);
    adapter.setTextKey("title");
    adapter.setImageKey("Image");
    adapter.loadObjects();
    ListView your_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    your_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

done, now objects are in a list

make sure that you have a sperate xml file for each parseobject, here i have it labaled as (R.id.post_item)

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need an AsyncTask for that...
Just create your query, invoke `findInBackGround()` which will create a Async for you, and on the callback, populate your listview.

```
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
                if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {

                    YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(context, results);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a ParseQueryAdapter, it's even simpler:

```
// create your query before, but do no call findInBackground. 
YourParseQueryAdapter adapter = new YourParseQueryAdapter(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                return query;
            }

        });
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Have a good read at the documentation again in case of any issues

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I need `query.whereEqualTo`, I need to write it at the create(), right?

Comment: yes. Just create your query in your onCreate. After it's created, use the code I've given you

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.idonaveh.guess.QuestionsList.onCreate(QuestionsList.java:99)`

Comment: It is the line `list.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: You know what.... do this entire tutorial, come back and if it doesn't work I'll solve your issues. It seems you don't even know how parse works and how basic adapter work

https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter

Comment: and you don't understand what my code does. So please go follow the tutorial, open the zip, compare the entire project vs yours and you'll figure things out.